# How to use AWS Polly with streaming transcription and translate to get real-time audio translation?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-polly, amazon-transcribe, amazon-translate

I want to implement audio translation to a conference web app.

I am thinking about using three AWS services for this (streaming transcribe, translate and Polly).

All the examples provided in AWS documentation are based on a single line of text being used. My question is how to pass the transcript derived from streaming transcription to aws translate and then to Polly to get a continuous audio stream that is playable in the browser?

Any help is much appreciated.